# How do I plot a matrix as a distance vs. time plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I am trying to plot the values (0's and 1's) that are stored in a 501x120 matrix. The plot is displaying but my x and y ticks correspond to the matrix indexes. I want to set these ticks to the corresponding distances (x-axis) and time (y-axis). I.e., the 501 rows correspond to a time series from 0 to 2 seconds with samples every 0.004 seconds. The columns are distances that go from (-600m to 600m) with a distance between columns of 10 m.

This is what I have written down so far:

```
  # Import libraries. The magic command '%matplotlib inline' shows figures as an output in the same jupyter notebook.
    %matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    v1 = 1500 #first layer velocity in m/s
    h1 = 200  #vertical distance to first reflector in m
    dt = 0.004 #sample rate in s
    channels = 120 #number of geophones
    dx = 10 #distance between geophones in m
    dhalf = channels/2*dx #divide total distance in two. This is because we will assume a source at the center of the array, i.e., a central-shot gather
    offsets = np.arange(channels)*dx-dhalf #creates numpy array with offsets to all 120 geophones
    
    td = [np.sqrt(x**2+ 4*h1**2) for x in offsets] #calculates reflection travel distances to each geophone
    tt = np.array(td)/v1 #calculates travel times as derived above
    
    num_samples = 501 # number of samples per trace
    seismic_data = np.zeros((num_samples,channels)) #creates a zero-matrix with a row per sample and a column per trace/channel. 
    for channel in range(channels): 
        sample=int(tt[channel]/dt)
        seismic_data [sample,channel]=1
        type(seismic_data)
            
    # This loop looks in each channel for the sample number closest to the one that corresponds to the reflected wave arrival and turns the 0 into a 1 (spike).
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))
    ax.imshow(seismic_data)
    ax.set_aspect(.3)
```

Comment: Good question. You can improve it by making a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a easier way to do this without having to create the meshgrid. It is by using the extent argument in plt.imshow. E.g.

```
ax.imshow(seismic_data,  aspect=1400,  extent= [np.min(offsets), np.max(offsets),np.max(time),np.min(time)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `contourf`:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(1)
img = np.random.randint(0,2, (501,120))

y,x = np.linspace(0,2,501), np.linspace(-600,600,120)

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(xx,yy,img, cmap='seismic')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. The last step towards my purpose was to invert the y axis and I did using: "plt.gca().invert_yaxis()". 

Thanks for your help!